# Creating Hotkeys in Firefox for bookmarks (bookmarklets)

Tags: firefox, hotkeys, bookmarklet

I would like to set up shortcuts (hotkeys) for several Firefox bookmarks (they're actually bookmarklets).  One example is the [pinboard.in bookmarklet](https://pinboard.in/howto/).  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: http://ask.metafilter.com/23032/How-do-I-assign-a-hotkey-to-a-Firefox-bookmark

Comment: The keyconfig extension described in the referenced article partially works.  The instructions are wrong (or perhaps difficult to follow).  When properly configured, a shortcut key will work, except NoScript seems to block it (unless the page is unblocked).  Clicking on the bookmarklet does not seem to be affected by NoScript, and I'd like the same to apply for the shortcut.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Initially, my solution was to assign a **keyword** to a bookmarklet and then use AutoHotkey to automate the following steps: pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to select the address bar, typing in the `keyword`, and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This works great with normal bookmarks, as you will be taken to a new page. However, with bookmarklets that work with the current page, this is clumsy and moves the keyboard's focus. So, in an effort to avoid the address bar altogether, I've devised the following solution.

### Setup:

1. Create a new folder in the Bookmarks Menu. Since we will be using the keyboard, give it a name that can be accessed with one keystroke, i.e. the first character is unique. I chose `.Hotkeyed`.
2. Move your bookmark to this folder, renaming them to begin with a character. This character will be used as part of the hotkey. For example, `a : Bookmark`.
3. Now, let's be sure we can **click** the bookmark using the keyboard. Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>.</kbd> should nagivate like so:

   [image: bookmark menu]

   and pressing <kbd>a</kbd> should click the first bookmark.

**AutoHotkey Script:**

Why press four keys, when you do it in less?

```
#a:: ;Win+A
KeyWait, LWin ; Win+Alt alone does nothing.
Send, {Alt} ;Menu >
Send, b ;Bookmarks >
Send, . ;.Hotkeyed >
Send, a ;Bookmark 1
Exit
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  This works but it changes the contents of the address bar.  Can you find a way to restore the address bar to its original contents?

Comment: @jdigital Sure! I will update the script.

Comment: Hold on... I have a better idea which avoids the address bar altogether.

Comment: @jdigital Updated. Let me know if this works for you. :)

Comment: Great idea: placing the bookmarklet in a menu location that is accessible by single letter navigation.  The `IfWinActive` code doesn't work for me, but you've provided enough information here to allow me to solve the problem.  Thank you!

Comment: @jdigital Ah. I sometimes have problems with `#IfWinActive`, too. I'll remove it, since it is not strictly necessary. You're welcome!

Comment: Is the `KeyWait` really needed?

Comment: [Win] may interfere with [Alt], so I use it as a precaution. You can try with and without `Keywait` to see if it makes a difference for you.

Comment: Works for me without KeyWait.  BTW, I think the problem with `#IfWinActive` is the `SetTitleMatchMode`.  If I use the `IfWinActive ahk ...` then it seems to work.

Comment: @jdigital Thanks for the tip! I will read up on the documentation and play around with it.

Comment: This is a great idea. I might use this for my mouse gestures. However, oftentimes I would like to use an easier-to-remember keyword to execute a certain bookmarklet, like "qr" for my QR-code bookmarklet. I used to do that by typing it into the address bar, but Firefox made that impossible, and I can't restore that function (tried every about:config and Noscript tip I could find). Do you happen to have any idea how I could make that work?

Comment: The only think I can think of is making a complicated menu structure for all my bookmarklets and using Inputbox in AHK to convert "qr" into the right sequence of keys to navigate the menus...but that would be a lot of work.

Comment: As of 2019 the above syntax no longer works. See the AutoHotKey docs for up to date syntax. Idea works with updated syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Once a keyword is assigned to the bookmarklet the standard way works, ie. typing the keyword and pressing `Enter`. What may be misleading is that FireFox doesn't display the bookmarklet in the location bar popup. But it works. Tested on FF 39.

Say you want to use SuperGenPass bookmarklet. Assign it a keyword, say `sgp` and it may be launched from location bar by typing `sgp` and pressing `Enter`.

Comment: This still works in 2023. Assign the keyword by r-clicking on the bookmarklet and selecting `Edit Bookmark`. To use the keyword while browsing use Alt-D to activate the location bar and then type your keyword. So in this case : `Alt-D` `sgp`

Answer (score 2):

You can have actual keyboard shortcuts for bookmarklets in Firefox. All you need is [Keyconfig](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/dorando-keyconfig/) - an add-on which allows you to rebind Firefox keyboard shortcuts.

Follow these steps:

1. Install Keyconfig
2. Edit your bookmark and add a unique keyword in the keyword field
3. Open Keyconfig (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>)
4. Click <kbd>Add a new key</kbd>
5. Paste following code into the text area below the name:
   `getShortcutOrURIAndPostData('KEYWORD').then(function(result){loadURI(result.url);});`
   replacing `KEYWORD` with the keyword you added to your bookmark, then click <kbd>OK</kbd>
6. Select that small text field under the list and press a key combination that you'd like to bind to your bookmark

   - If a message pops up saying that this combination is already used - you can find and disable the action that is already bound to it, or choose another combination
7. Click <kbd>Apply</kbd> and you're done. You can add another shortcut or close Keyconfig window

Comment: Thanks a lot, MacGyver! Combined with [my answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1148576/143340), this brings back the functionality of the disappeared "Open Chromeless" extension. And I even already had the Keyconfig addon installed, but in an older version – so second thanks for pointing out the updated version: +1 for your answer :)

Comment: KeyConfig no longer exists for more recent versions of Firefox.  A lot of its functionality was taken over by the Firefox built-in `Manage Extension Shortcuts` (from the gear-menu of `about:addons`) but that is limited to addon shortcuts as the name implies.

Comment: This is sooooooooo irritating. Every so often a solution for doing what I want to do (use a KEYBOARD SHORTCUT to go to a particular URL) comes along and disappears after a couple of years (or less). "Manage Extension Shortcuts" does absolutely NOT do what is being asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not quite what you are asking, it might be of interest. I do the following:

- right click on the **bookmark** you want
- select **copy** from the menu
- go to the **desktop**
- right click on the desktop and click **paste shortcut**
- right click on the shortcut once it is in place, select the **Web Document tab** and enter the short cut you want in the Shortcut Key field.
- click **OK** - you are done (if you like you can change the name of the shortcut on the desktop to include the description of the short cut, e.g. "<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> - Google")

Advantages: works with no installation of add-on; allows you to summon up the link even if you are not in firefox; you can use any shortcut that does not clash with something else, and are not restricted to CTRL 1-9 or something

Disadvantage: you end up with a bunch of shortcuts sitting on your desktop; if you delete the shortcut you have lost the "keybinding"

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (not only for Firefox but for any application...)

Comment: We need to know an operating system first. AHK is for Windows.

Comment: I'm running Windows.  I've written AHK scripts, but can't figure out how to write a script to activate a Bookmarklet.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Shortkeys (Custom Keyboard Shortcuts)](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/shortkeys/) addon for Firefox.

> Access Bookmark Toolbar items with a keyboard shortcut. The default is
> Control+1-9. Change it in the preferences.

Comment: This extension works for bookmarks, but doesn't seem to work for bookmarklets.

Comment: I'm using this extension just for bookmarklets. But I noticed it will only work if the bookmark toolbar is visible.

Comment: It is not working for bookmarklets in Firefox 97.

Comment: I've updated the link, the old link didn't work anymore. Tested in 97.0b9 with a JS snippet.