# How can I launch FireFox with no window frame or tabs / address bar?

Tags: windows, firefox, browser, autohotkey, browser-tabs

I am looking for a way to launch Firefox from a script or command line without any window frame, address bar, or tabs. I'd like to be able to launch this at a given window **size and position** on screen.

Illustration:

[image: firefox browser]

I'd like to only be able to see the section that is comprised of the red box, and the area inside of it.

Using AutoHotKey in Windows, I've been able to launch FireFox at a given window size / position. However, If I try to launch Firefox in "chromeless" mode, and try to resize the window with AHK, I end up with a 0 px by 0 px browser window.

My AutoHotKey Script:

```
Run, C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe -chrome http://www.google.com/
WinWait, Mozilla Firefox
WinMove,,,100,100,400,300
```

I've found related questions, but I've not found a solution:

[How can I launch a browser with no window frame or tabs](https://superuser.com/questions/459775/how-can-i-launch-a-browser-with-no-window-frame-or-tabs-address-bar)

[How can I run Firefox with no tab bar, no top bar, no address bar](https://superuser.com/questions/782653/how-can-i-run-firefox-with-no-tab-bar-no-top-bar-no-address-bar-and-not-stret)

Comment: [R-Kiosk extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/r-kiosk/)

Comment: [mKiosk extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/mkiosk/)

Comment: It looks like it will take a lot of modification to one of these kiosk extensions to produce the result I'm after. I'll dig in and see what I can make happen.

Comment: Related: [Launching Firefox into “chromeless” mode from command prompt](https://superuser.com/q/55915/143340) (not sure if that still works). And just found *after* writing my below answer: [As a user, how can I open a site in a popup window without toolbars?](https://superuser.com/q/942442/143340)

Comment: @user498283 suggests pressing `F11`

Comment: Here's a recent question on point: https://superuser.com/questions/1356778/firefox-quantum-kiosk-mode.

Answer (score 3):

Wanted to leave this here, it seems to be a barely-documented feature of Firefox called "Single Site Browser":

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1292666

Apparently, Firefox disallowed hiding of the location bar unless you launch Firefox with this mode. This SSB mode does still show the window frame (caption with window title, maximise, close buttons, etc.), but all other window chrome is gone.

Now I'm looking for a way to use add-ons in this mode... :(

Comment: Answers should do their best to be self-contained. In short, you should copy the instructions from the link you posted and "quote/cite" them in your answer.

Comment: no longer works since 2021

Answer (score 2):

For that, there once was an addon called "Open Chromeless" – but it was removed from AMO. A work-around [is described here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/998726); I've just checked it and it seems to work. Partly. Cannot get rid of the addressbar, and there's a frame around the window. If you can live with that:

1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> to open the Scratchpad
2. In the editor, enter

   ```
   window.open("https://superuser.com/", "_blank","width=800,height=600,resizable");
   ```

   (replace the URL with the one you want to use)
3. Click "Run" on the scratchpad toolbar

Now a new "chrome-less" window should open with the page specified. Resize it to your needs:

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot of the "chromeless window" (click to enlarge)</sup>

Right-click next to the addressbar, as shown in the screenshot, lets you disable the address bar as well (untick "Navigation toolbar") – but note that would remove it from your main window as well.

I'm aware this does not *fully* match your request (it's not launching from the command line, and leaves at least a frame around the window), but it comes as close as I could get to it.

Answer (score 0):

When I wanted to do this full screen I did something like this:

`firefox -url http://superuser.com -fullscreen`

But I had to install an add-on to get rid of all the extra decorations.

"full fullscreen" if I remember the name correctly

For smaller geometries, I don't know

Comment: In my testing, the "-fullscreen" option does nothing. My searches indicate that others have had the same result.