# Firefox Quantum - Kiosk Mode

Tags: windows-10, kiosk, firefox-quantum

I currently use this method to emulate chrome's kiosk-mode in Firefox Quantum on Windows 10:

1. Install Firefox Quantum
2. Install AddOn AutoFullscreen
3. in Firefox's address-bar, type `about:config` and set the parameters `zoom.maxPercent` & `zoom.minPercent` to 100 (hence, disabling zoom)
4. **CREATE** Folder/File `"C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile>.default\chrome\userChrome.css"` with the following content:

   > ```
   > @namespace 
   > url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");
   > #fullscr-toggler { display:none!important; }
   > ```
5. Disable all System-Notifications in Windows 10
6. Disable (if possible) all System-Touch-Gestures to disable all Windows 10 Bars and Menus by going to the **Local Policy Editor** -> Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Edge UI and disable `allow edge swipe`

It would be interesting to know if there are better/easier alternatives ways to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox does not support real kiosk mode.
The add-ons below might help in setting it up :

- [Modern Kiosk](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modern-kiosk/?src=search)
- [Kiosk Mode Touch Keyboard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/kiosk-mode-touch-keyboard/?src=search)

The following are ideas for additions to your procedure :

- Use a separate profile for kiosk mode and start firefox with `-no-remote -p`
- Set the home page
- If the Bookmarks Toolbar is visible, add useful links
- Turn off password management
- Make Firefox automatically delete personal data and history on exit

Comment: Useful ideas, indeed. The "Modern-Kiosk" add-on looks promising, but in its current experimental state is not really an option for production environments, since it lacks some key features (autostart) and still feels a bit buggy. Will hopefully get better soon.

Comment: The best way to make it better is to communicate with the author. Interest in his product does encourage a developer.