# Firefox hide or disable More tools and Options icons

Tags: firefox, icons, display-settings

I've been looking into a way to disable the More tools and Options icons on Firefox but couldn't get too much success.

[image: Please view Screen-shot by clicking here]

Our company has a few public computers running on Win10 and Firefox 69.0 (64-bit). What I need to achieve eventually, is to disable the settings so that the user cannot change the browser settings like homepage. The More tools icon will give you the option to customise the toolbar and eventually backdoor to the settings.

After some researching I have now been able to disable or hide some other menu buttons or menu bar by editing userChrome.css file. But still those two icons I couldn't disable or hide them.

Could you please advise if you have any clue for the item/icon ID to hide or any add-on I can use? Thank you all for any contribution!

Comment: You are probably on the wrong path here. There are also keyboard shortcuts which the user can use to access Options (Ctrl-Shift-A for Extensions, F12 for development console, etc. etc.). Better start looking into special kiosk software which was build for that.

Comment: Firefox doesn't really have a kiosk mode, which is what you seem to be looking for: https://superuser.com/questions/1356778/firefox-quantum-kiosk-mode. You could try [Firefox for Enterprise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Enterprise_deployment), it seems to offer more options for restriction and configuration